# Unable to locate authorization token when calling codecatalyst from AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecatalyst

When I try to use the AWS CLI to run commands for the new [AWS CodeCatalyst](https://codecatalyst.aws) service, the command hangs for a bit and I keep getting the same error: `Unable to locate authorization token`

I verified that my AWS profile/credentials are pointing to the AWS account that I linked when I signed up for CodeCatalyst.

```
% aws --profile dev-admin s3 ls

2020-06-03 06:44:13 bucket1
2022-10-31 16:45:08 bucket2

% aws --profile dev-admin codecatalyst list-access-tokens

Unable to locate authorization token
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

You can't use your normal AWS credentials when running AWS CLI commands for `codecatalyst` because CodeCatalyst uses our AWS Builder ID as your user to authenticate and you need a special profile for that.

To get this working, add the following to your `~/.aws/config` file to create a profile (calling it `codecatalyst` in this example):

```
[profile codecatalyst]
region = us-west-2
sso_session = codecatalyst

[sso-session codecatalyst]
sso_region = us-east-1
sso_start_url = https://view.awsapps.com/start
sso_registration_scopes = codecatalyst:read_write
```

Then you can run the `login` command to login and get your credentials setup in the CLI.  It will redirect you to a browser window where you need to login with your AWS Builder ID that you used to sign up with CodeCatalyst.

```
% aws sso login --profile codecatalyst
```

After this, you can successfully run CodeCatalyst CLI commands using your new profile:

```
% aws codecatalyst list-access-tokens --profile codecatalyst
{
    "items": [
...
    ]
}
```

Reference:

- [Code Catalyst CLI Setup Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecatalyst/latest/userguide/set-up-cli.html)